# mysql-5.6.27| reset root password | no password field

Tags: mysql

I installed the "Mac OS X 10.9 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive" on mysql website and i i can't access as root ("mysql -uroot -p") because i don't know the password. Is there a default password or something? so I access the mysql as anonymous to use "udo ./mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables" on command line. I tried the

```
update user set password=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where User='root';
```

query to reset the root password. However the funny thing is the password field is deprecated. However there is another command to be able to the MySQL server as root using the new password the recommended by MySQL.

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```

but the problem is it normally without the --skip-grant-tables and --skip-networking options.

What can i do? I deleted the last version that i downloaded and installed the 10.9 today. I thought the default password was not existed! But I can't access.
Please let me know how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to reset Password for MySql MySQL 5.7 on MAC OSX

1. open shell/terminal window
2. sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
3. sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
4. open another shell/terminal window
5. sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
6. mysql>use mysql
7. update user set authentication_string=password('1111') where user='root';

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL offers a way for you to log in to MySQL server without password, by using an external MySQL configuration file.  Have a look at this link:

http://xmodulo.com/how-to-log-in-to-mysql-server-without-password.html